# How to remove the decimals when Subtracting casted Dates (EPOCH) in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, rounding

I am subtracting two epoch dates from each other to get a positive Integer that shows the number of days that has passed from creation to completion (aka modification).

Here is a snippet from my query, that accomplishes that from SQL Developer 20.2.0:

```
(TO_DATE('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + (DATEMODIFIED / 86400))-(TO_DATE('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + (DATECREATED / 86400)) AS "Age at Completion",
```

However, this results in an output of:
74.2922256787899889869

I don't need to see all those decimal places. A result such as this would be sufficient:

74.2922256787899889869 = **74**

or

74.5922256787899889869 = **74**

I think the **ROUND** function might be what I am looking for but I have no clue how to actually use it in that line. Can someone please assist? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(A + B) - (A + C) == A + B - A - C == B - C
```

So why not simply `ROUND((DATECREATED - DATEMODIFIED) / 86400)`?

Or maybe this:

```
DATEMODIFIED  * INTERVAL '1' SECOND - DATECREATED * INTERVAL '1' SECOND

EXTRACT(DAY FROM (DATECREATED - DATEMODIFIED) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND)
```

Comment: That give's the following result:    **+** 74 **06:46:15.000000** how do i get rid of the bold part's, so its just an integer?

Comment: You can use `EXTRACT` function.

Comment: can you help with that please? I am fairly new to SQL if you cant tell :)

Comment: Well heck that then turns the result into **-74**, is there a way to just get  **74** as the result and nothing else?

Comment: I modified it just a bit to get my desired result:

EXTRACT(DAY FROM (DATECREATED - DATEMODIFIED) * INTERVAL '-1' SECOND) AS "Age at Completion",

Comment: adding that "-" before the 1 turned it into just 74 as I was looking for.

Comment: Or use `ABS(EXTRACT(DAY FROM (DATECREATED - DATEMODIFIED) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND))`